# How to delete a group, of which I am not an owner, in a subsite

Tags: groups, delete

I have created a subsite in my site and then the owners group for that subsite. I was a member of that group and I believe the owner was set to the group itself. Then I deleted myself from the group, so now I am not an owner any more. Is there a way to delete this group via UI?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to delete it from the UI is if you are a site collection administrator or get yourself put back into the Owner group that was managing that group.